# How to get the index label for a series returned by groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I've read in a timecard CSV file consisting of daily entries: 'User','Hours'.
I want to know the list of Users who submitted a partial timecard (e.g., less than 40 hrs/week).

```
summed_entries = df.groupby('User')['Hours'].sum() 
# This returns me a Series of Users and their total hours logged. 

for item in summed_entries:
    if item < 40:
       print(???) # This is where I want to return the User, available to me as the Series index label. I am unclear how to go about this.
```

Comment: What does `print(item)` look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to implement a for loop in pandas, this seems to suffice for your purpose:

```
summed_entries = df.groupby('User')['Hours'].sum()
summed_entries = summed_entries[summed_entries < 40]
```

To get the list of names:

```
list(summed_entries.index.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not iterate to find out that since looping takes more time. Instead, you can do the following

You can reset the index as Users while grouping by the condition

```
summed_entries = df.groupby('User')['Hours'].sum().reset_index('Users')
```

Now instead of looping, you will have to just locate the records in the dataframe

```
summed_entries.loc[summed_entries['hours'] < 40]
```